# Very slow to open a file with application:openFile: after returning

Tags: macos, cocoa, appleevents

My application implements the NSApplicationDelegate method -application:openFile: in its app delegate. There seems to be a problem new to OS 10.8 where after receiving the apple event to open a file, five seconds pass before some kind of internal timeout is hit, a response is sent to the apple event, and the calling app (e.g., applescript editor) proceeds.

In detail, here's what I see. After application:openFile: returns YES, I can see that -[NSAppleEventManager suspendCurrentAppleEvent] is called:

```
#0  0x00007fff8f07b5ed in -[NSAppleEventManager suspendCurrentAppleEvent] ()
#1  0x00007fff8f90458e in -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenDocumentsForURLs:] ()
#2  0x00007fff8f903b55 in -[NSApplication(NSScripting) handleOpenScriptCommand:] ()
#3  0x00007fff90770cac in __invoking___ ()
#4  0x00007fff90770b47 in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#5  0x00007fff90770d19 in -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] ()
#6  0x00007fff8f10121c in -[NSScriptCommand _sendToRemainingReceivers] ()
#7  0x00007fff8f1014c6 in -[NSScriptCommand executeCommand] ()
#8  0x00007fff8f11983a in -[NSScriptingAppleEventHandler handleCommandEvent:withReplyEvent:] ()
#9  0x00007fff8f00635b in -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] ()
#10 0x00007fff8f0061bd in _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler ()
#11 0x00007fff93844f68 in aeDispatchAppleEvent ()
#12 0x00007fff93844dc9 in dispatchEventAndSendReply ()
#13 0x00007fff93844c89 in aeProcessAppleEvent ()
#14 0x00007fff8c141e29 in AEProcessAppleEvent ()
#15 0x00007fff8f6b22a6 in _DPSNextEvent ()
#16 0x00007fff8f6b1862 in -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] ()
#17 0x00007fff8f6a8c03 in -[NSApplication run] ()
#18 0x00007fff8f64d656 in NSApplicationMain ()
#19 0x0000000100001d7c in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fff5fbff7c0) at main.m:23
```

After five seconds, -[NSAppleEventManager resumeWithSuspensionID:] is called:

```
#0  0x00007fff8f07b6be in -[NSAppleEventManager resumeWithSuspensionID:] ()
#1  0x00007fff8f90585f in __block_global_1 ()
#2  0x00007fff9073a4b4 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#3  0x00007fff90739fcd in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#4  0x00007fff9071f7b9 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#5  0x00007fff9071edd2 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#6  0x00007fff8c137774 in RunCurrentEventLoopInMode ()
#7  0x00007fff8c137512 in ReceiveNextEventCommon ()
#8  0x00007fff8c1373a3 in BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode ()
#9  0x00007fff8f6b1fa3 in _DPSNextEvent ()
#10 0x00007fff8f6b1862 in -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] ()
#11 0x00007fff8f6a8c03 in -[NSApplication run] ()
#12 0x00007fff8f64d656 in NSApplicationMain ()
#13 0x0000000100001d7c in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fff5fbff7c0) at main.m:23
```

Evidently, some kind of timeout was reached since resumeWithSuspensionID: is called from a timer and it is always very close to 5 second between my application:openFile: method returning and resumeWithSuspensionID: being called.

After this, things proceed normally: whatever applescript invoked "open file ..." continues at the next statement. There don't appear to be any errors--it just times out waiting for something.

I turned on AEDebugSends and AEDebugReceives. Here's what I see up to the timeout:

```
Aug 23 21:26:05 mymachine.local iTerm[4819] <Info>: _aeMachPortCallback(), got a message, @ 0x0x7fff5fbfe1f0 size=972 info=0 (_aeMachPortCallback()/AEMach.cp #643) main
Aug 23 21:26:05 mymachine.local iTerm[4819] <Notice>: AE2000 (4819: Received an event:
------oo start of event oo------
aevt('aevt'\'odoc' transactionID=0 returnID=3711 sourcePSN=[0x0,6f06f "AppleScript Editor"] eventSource=3 sourceUID=501 sourceGID=20 sourceEUID=501 sourceEGID=20 sourcePID=3551 auditToken=[501,501,20,501,20,3551,100005,3551]{ '----':obj ('obj '{ 'form':enum('name'), 'want':type('file'), 'seld':utxt('utxt'(TEXT("Macintosh HD:Users:georgen:Library:Application Support:iTerm:version.txt"))), 'from':null() }), &'csig':magn(65536) })
------oo  end of event  oo------
(aeProcessIncomingEvent()/AEMach.cp #1445) main
2012-08-23 21:26:05.451 iTerm[4819:707] Command: NSCoreSuite.Open
Direct Parameter: /Users/georgen/Library/Application Support/iTerm/version.txt
Receivers: (null)
Arguments:     {
        "" = "/Users/georgen/Library/Application Support/iTerm/version.txt";
    }
```

Then, after the timeout I see this (which is logged because I also set NSScriptingDebugLogLevel to 1):

```
2012-08-23 21:26:36.347 iTerm[4819:707] Result: <null>
```

My openFile: method doesn't do anything besides return YES. Is there something else I need to do to make the framework happy?

Comment: is your app sandboxed? And maybe it'd be good to show some code? .. no idea atm